# Struggle to have two datapoints with same x and y values behave like stackedColumn chart type i.e. on top of each other

Tags: canvasjs

I have the following example of data  with some Points having same x,y values which means they apear in the Column chart overlayed on each other - is there a way to have them appear stcked on top of each other like in stackedColumn chart type.

see working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/yjxoLr9e/

portions of the json data:

```
"purchaseRows": [
{x: new Date("2017-03-10"), y:600},
{x: new Date("2017-04-06"), y:504},
{x: new Date("2017-04-06"), y:600},
{x: new Date("2017-05-03"), y:504},
{x: new Date("2017-05-03"), y:504},
{x: new Date("2017-06-05"), y:504},
{x: new Date("2017-08-07"), y:714},
{x: new Date("2017-09-04"), y:714},
{x: new Date("2017-10-02"), y:504},
{x: new Date("2017-11-06"), y:504},
{x: new Date("2017-12-04"), y:540},
],
```

and the data Array:

```
data: [     { type: "stepLine", showInLegend: true, lineThickness: 2, name: "Transactions", markerSize: 5, markerType: "circle", color: "SteelBlue", dataPoints: json.transactionData },
                    { type: "stepLine", lineDashType: "dot", showInLegend: true, lineThickness: 2, name: "Stock forecast", markerSize: 5, markerType: "circle", color: "SteelBlue", dataPoints: json.stockForecast },
                    { type: "stackedColumn", showInLegend: true, lineThickness: 0, name: "Backlog", markerSize: 8, markerType: "circle", color: "coral", dataPoints: json.currentbacklog },
                    { type: "stackedColumn", showInLegend: true, lineThickness: 0, name: "Demand", markerSize: 8, markerType: "circle", color: "red", dataPoints: json.unconsumedFcst },
                    { type: "line", showInLegend: true, lineThickness: 0, name: "Stock", markerSize: 8, markerType: "circle", color: "red", dataPoints: json.currentStock },
                    { type: "column", showInLegend: true, lineThickness: 2, name: "Purchase rows", markerSize: 8, markerType: "circle", color: "lightgreen", dataPoints: json.purchaseRows }

        ],
```

Comment: CanvasJS do have stacked column chart. You probably can use that. Here is the documentation page on same. : http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-stacked-column-chart/

Answer (score 1):

Beevk is correct chart type stackedColumn dors the trick.